# Javascript hidden element taking up space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, show-hide

I'm dipping a toe into the world of JavaScript and creating a menu for my mobile website.

The idea is that there will be a menu bar at the top, if you click it, it will slide open pushing the page content with it. If you click the menu bar again the menu will slide closed and the content will follow it back into the original position. It's all working really well with one exception. When I toggle the menu closed the content follows it up and then pings back down leaving space for the hidden menu. (Hope that makes sense)

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I get the page content to ignore the hidden menu?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hide();

    $('#menu_head').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#nav_mobile {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Pacifico, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%
    }   
#nav_mobile #nav_menu {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav_mobile #menu_head {
    background: #070707;
    width: 100%;
    color: #454955;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav_mobile .dropdown {
    background: #070707;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav_mobile a {
    display: block;
}
```

I've seen lots of articles saying change display to hidden but if I do that it doesn't fix the problem. In fact it makes it worse as the menu then doesn't slide as one, instead each menu item slides independently of the others.

HTML

```
<nav id="nav_mobile" role="navigation">
    <h2 id="menu_head">Menu</h2>
    <ul id="nav_menue">
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/index') ?>" class="dropdown">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/news') ?>" class="dropdown">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/gallery') ?>" class="dropdown">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/band') ?>" class="dropdown">Band</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/music') ?>" class="dropdown">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/video') ?>" class="dropdown">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/shows') ?>" class="dropdown">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/contact') ?>" class="dropdown">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/mailing_list') ?>" class="dropdown">Join the Mailing List</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: @Tessa I would really, really strongly recommend you do not start with animation with jQuery. Take a look at how you use CSS to create a solution. Your JavaScript would be very simple, and you may find it works more like how you expect. I'm recommending this because using jQuery for things like animation is something that people did years ago now, and it's something most try to avoid! You can learn something that's relevant now if you ditch the jQuery animations.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using CSS to do what I want as this was my preference but the drop down menu kept disappearing behind elements on the page such as the photo gallery. I was unable to resolve the problem even with the help of stack overflow and most tutorials I looked at told me to use Javascript

Comment: Actually, to continue from my last comment, if you used CSS, you wouldn't even need JavaScript at all! Take a look here: http://www.valdelama.com/css-responsive-navigation The main advantage is that if you use CSS to do this, you can leverage hardware acceleration - which makes things a LOT smoother, especially so on older devices.

Comment: To clarify, by all means, use JavaScript if you feel that it would be easier, or if you simply want to for the experience. It's only jQuery I'm urging you to not use. It's slow, makes code more difficult to organise, big, and just generally unnecessary these days is all. Just remember, jQuery !== JavaScript

Comment: Well, jQuery is javascript, but javascript is not jQuery ;-) To make matters even worse I'd say using jQuery for animations is perfectly fine. Best case scenario - learn both, and use what you ultimately prefer.

Comment: Thanks Seer & Mackan. I do really appreciate your input. I am new to web development and currently doing as the books tell me until I have enough experience to know better so hearing others opinions on how to do things is very helpful :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting the anchors within your list items, your list items and their container don't get hidden at all.

Target the `<ul>`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navMenue = $('#nav_menue');
    $navMenue.hide();

    $('#menu_head').click(function () {
        $navMenue.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ds52aLy/)